# Do we know anything about Hera's brother?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, the-bad-batch

**spoilers for *The Bad Batch***

In *Jedi Night* in season 4 of *Rebels,* Thrawn reveals to Hera that he knows, from her kalikori, that she had a brother who died when he was young.  This is a minor detail, but one that never comes up again.  Hera doesn't mention her brother when Omega tells her about her own clone brothers in *The Bad Batch,* and in the novel *Lords of the Sith* Cham Syndulla never talks about his son.  Do we have any information in the canon about her brother, or is it just what we have in *Rebels?*

Comment: [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hera_Syndulla%27s_brother) mentions a single indirect mention to Hera's brother in Bad Batch episode, Rescue on Ryloth, but I don't recall it. Aside from that, Thrawn's mention in regards to Hera's kalikori is the only one listed.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Yeah, I saw that listing.  It's VERY indirect, and it seems to be more speculation than anything else.  When Omega says "He's my brother.  They all are." Hera looks away and says "You're lucky."  The conversation continues in a different direction, but I suppose that line was supposed to be a reference to her dead brother.

Answer (score -1):

I think the dead brother is referring to Howzer. Howzer and Hera seemed close almost sibling like. He stuck his neck out for her multiple times, so he clearly cares about her well-being. There’s also the fact that he has defected and been captured so he is definitely in danger. Hera’s no stranger to the found family dynamic, so I don’t think an adopted clone brother would be too far fetched. It’s really a matter of if we can figure out dates, or get confirmation of things. Really all speculation here though. Any other thoughts are welcome because I’ve just made myself very sad with this

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  But that doesn't fit "a brother who died when he was young."  Even if she considers Howzer a "brother" now, he obviously isn't the one Thrawn was referring to who died young.